# Saving Time into Postgres database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Python application which utilizes SQLAlchemy to interface with a Postgres database. I am running into some issues saving a time object into the database.

I define two time columns where db is a SQLAlchemy object:

```
offHours                = db.Column(db.Time)
onHours                 = db.Column(db.Time)
```

Elsewhere in the code, I try to save a time value from a string:

```
offHours = "06:23"
onHours = "14:34"
```

Python then throws the following:

```
time data '06:23' does not match format '%HH:%MM'
```

I am confused by this error because the input is a valid 24 hour time. Additionally, the Python docs state that the correct formatter for a 24 hour timestamp is '%H:%M'. If this is the case, why is SQLAlchemy using '%HH:%MM' as it's time formatter?

In short, what am I doing wrong when saving these times? Is it my input or possibly some issue with my database configuration?

Comment: It may be that the quotes are required to match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving datetime.time object and not string.